# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{a_i}}$ if $a_n=(2^n+3^n)^\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\displaystyle a_n=(2^n+3^n)^\frac{1}{n}$. Compute the limit $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_i}}$$

By squeeze theorem, limit of $a_n$ is $3$. Further the sequence $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_i}$ is strictly monotonic and diverges to infinity since the limit of $n^{th}$ term of the series $\displaystyle \sum_i\dfrac{1}{a_i}$ is not $0$ infact $1/3$. Hence by Cesaro Stolz  theorem for $\cdot/\infty$ case,
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_i}}=3.$$

Is my reasoning correct? Are there more easier ways to solve this?

Comment: What you have done is correct and it seems to be the best way to answer the question.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thank you Sir.

Comment: This works for any mean and any sequence that approaches a limit.

Comment: @martycohen Does that mean I can employ Cauchy's first theorem on limits here?

Comment: @YadatiKiran:How you used squeeze theorem to show $a_n \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$a_n =  3\Big(1+(\frac23)^n\Big)^{1/n}=3\exp\Big(\frac1n\ln(1+(2/3)^n)\Big)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}3$.
The rest follows from Cesaro sums:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{a_k}=\frac{1}{3}$